# How to show the menu list by clicking the button?

Tags: android, menu

There is a button in my application, I want to do that if someone click on this button, the menu will show up.

[image]

It will be like this menu on the first picture.
How to do this?

Answer (score 13):

Use need to call [Activity.openOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29) on Button click event.

in your button click write

```
this.openOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: very smart answer

Comment: Hi, can you suggest doing the same in Fragment? activity

Answer (score 8):

This is how I implemented `showPopUp()` function in Kotlin and I followed the same documentation that @umesh mentioned: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics./ui/menus.html#PopupMenu. Then you can call the function in your `onClick()` function.

```
     private fun showPopup(v: View) {
         PopupMenu(this, v).apply {
            setOnMenuItemClickListener(object: PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
                override fun onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
                    return when (item?.itemId) {

                        R.id.settings -> {
                            dosomething()
                            true
                        }
                        else -> false
                    }
                }

            })
            inflate(R.menu.menu)
            show()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
 private void showPopup(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
       MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();

    }

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    showPopup(v);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow below url, it has example
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu